# Libzip - Archive error always returns ZIP_ER_OK, even if archive fails to be created

Tags: c++, libzip

I'm using a switch statement to check the value of the error code in the libzip zip archive that I'm creating. However, it never seems to return anything other than 0, even when I cause it to fail on purpose. (I'm causing it to fail by trying to copy files to a usb drive that is 100% full).

How is my usage incorrect here?

```
                int error = 0;
                zip_t * zip = zip_open(externalDevicePath.c_str(), ZIP_CREATE, &error);
                zip_add_dir(zip,(institutionId + DIR_SLASH + userId).c_str());

                string instAndUserPath = basePath + DIR_SLASH + institutionId + DIR_SLASH + userId;
                string stbackupPath = basePath + DIR_SLASH + "STBackups";

                ESFileUtilsCommon::addDirectoryToZip(instAndUserPath,zip,(institutionId + DIR_SLASH + userId).c_str());
                ESFileUtilsCommon::addDirectoryToZip(stbackupPath,zip,"STBackups");
                ESFileUtilsCommon::addDirectoryContentsToZip(basePath, zip);

                zip_close(zip);

                switch (error){
                case ZIP_ER_OK:         
                    mapper.setResult(RESULT_SUCCESS);
                    retval = CefV8Value::CreateString(mapper.getMappedJsonResponse());
                    return true;
                    break;
                default:
                    mapper.setResult(RESULT_FAILURE);
                    retval = CefV8Value::CreateString(mapper.getMappedJsonResponse());
                    return false;
                    break;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can't test your code. However, from the fact that you are checking `error` long after `zip_open`, I think you are confused by the how error works in libzip.

The `int error` you pass to `zip_open` is only responsible to `zip_open`, *not* any potential errors afterwards. If you want to know whether `zip_dir_add` has an error, you need to check it's own return value, see its documentation: https://libzip.org/documentation/zip_dir_add.html. You can also use the `zip_get_error()` function to check the latest error, see documentation: https://libzip.org/documentation/zip_get_error.html.